# При запуске кода с библиотекой SFML окно вывода автоматически закрывается, написан код на С++

Tags: c++, sfml

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>

// Определение перечисления Direction для направлений движения
enum Direction { ВВЕРХ, ВНИЗ, ВЛЕВО, ВПРАВО };

// Определение класса Grid для представления игрового поля
class Grid
{
public:
    // Инициализация сетки заданного размера
    Grid(int size)
    {
        m_size = size;
        m_grid.resize(size, std::vector<int>(size, 0));
    }

    // Получение размера сетки
    int size() const { return m_size; }

    // Получение значения плитки в заданной позиции
    int get(int x, int y) const { return m_grid[y][x]; }

    // Установка значения плитки в заданной позиции
    void set(int x, int y, int val) { m_grid[y][x] = val; }

    // Проверка наличия пустой ячейки в сетке
    bool hasEmptyCell() const {
        for (const auto& row : m_grid) {
            for (int tile : row) {
                if (tile == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Добавление новой плитки в сетку
    void addTile() {
        // Поиск случайной пустой ячейки
        std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> emptyCells;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m_size; ++j) {
                if (m_grid[i][j] == 0) {
                    emptyCells.push_back({ i, j });
                }
            }
        }
        if (!emptyCells.empty()) {
            // Размещение новой плитки в случайной пустой ячейке
            std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
            auto randomCell = emptyCells[std::rand() % emptyCells.size()];
            m_grid[randomCell.first][randomCell.second] = (std::rand() % 2 + 1) * 2;
        }
    }

  // Движение плиток в сетке
bool move(Direction dir) {
    bool moved = false;
    // Реализация движения
    return moved;
}

    // Отрисовка сетки
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window, int cellSize, int margin) {
        // Отрисовка сетки
    }

private:
    // Размер сетки
    int m_size;

    // Сетка
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_grid;
};

int main()
{
    // Создание окна
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "2048");
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    // Создание игрового поля
    const int gridSize = 4;
    Grid grid(gridSize);

    // Установка других состояний игры
    bool gameOver = false;

    // Загрузка шрифта для счета
    sf::Font font;
    if (!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf")) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Установка размера ячейки и отступа
    const int cellSize = 200;
    const int margin = 20;

    // Обработка ввода
    sf::Vector2i lastMousePos;
    sf::Event event;

    // Игровой цикл
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // Обработка событий
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            lastMousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Escape)) {
            window.close();
        }
        sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
        if (mousePos != lastMousePos) {
            // Обработка движения мыши
        }

        // Обновление состояния игры
        if (grid.hasEmptyCell()) {
            grid.addTile();
        }

        // Обработка ввода
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Up)) {
            if (grid.move(ВВЕРХ)) {
                // Обработка успешного хода
            }
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Down)) {
            if (grid.move(ВНИЗ)) {
                // Обработка успешного хода
            }
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Left)) {
            if (grid.move(ВЛЕВО)) {
                // Обработка успешного хода
            }
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Right)) {
            if (grid.move(ВПРАВО)) {
                // Обработка успешного хода
            }
        }

        // Проверка завершения игры
        if (!grid.hasEmptyCell()) {
            // Проверка условий победы
            bool won = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; ++j) {
                    if (grid.get(i, j) == 2048) {
                        won = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (won) {
                // Обработка условия победы
                std::cout << "Поздравляем! Вы победили!" << std::endl;
                gameOver = true;
            }
            else {
                // Обработка условия завершения игры
                std::cout << "Игра окончена!" << std::endl;
                gameOver = true;
            }
        }

        // Отрисовка игры
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        grid.draw(window, cellSize, margin);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: код похож на отрыжку чатгтп